# Accessing WebKit Devtools JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, webkit, google-chrome-devtools

I noticed something in Chrome the other day- I had opened Developer Tools, and then hit view source and was initially surprised to notice that apparently the developer tools window is coded in HTML and JavaScript- you can see that by putting the following into the Chrome address bar:

```
view-source:chrome://devtools/devtools.html
```

Two things struck me- first, the codes copyright belongs to Apple (considering their backing of WebKit, thats not too surprising), and secondly, it appears that you cannot access the JavaScript, CSS or Image files directly through Chrome by clicking on links in the source code.

So two questions:

Where are the DevTools assets stored on my computer or how can I otherwise access them? Or even better, can someone identify the library that is used and let me know how its licensed? I'm always on the look out for a well implemented UI toolkit- and Devtools looks great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Mac the Web Inspector is located at:
/System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Resources/inspector/

The inspector is entirely self contained code, no external libraries were used. When you know your code is only going to be run in one web browser…

The license for WebKit is generally LGPL and BSD however the Web Inspector files all have differing copyright owners (Apple, Google, Nokia, etc) and the following license:

> Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
>   modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are
>   met:
>
> 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
>       notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
> 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
>       notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
>       documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
> 3. Neither the name of Apple Computer, Inc. ("Apple") nor the names of
>       its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
>       from this software without specific prior written permission.
>
>    THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND ANY  EXPRESS OR IMPLIED
>      WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED  WARRANTIES OF
>      MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE  DISCLAIMED.
>      IN NO EVENT SHALL APPLE OR ITS CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY  DIRECT,
>      INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES 
>      (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
>      SERVICES;  LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION)
>      HOWEVER CAUSED AND  ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT,
>      STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT  (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING
>      IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF  THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE
>      POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

Since it is open source you can extent and contribute to the project, see http://webkit.org

Comment: This is right _on a Mac_. I wouldn't know where to look on Windows though.

Comment: Thanks and apologies for the late acceptance- I happen to be on a mac

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to see the content of the files use the following uris

```
chrome-devtools://devtools/DevTools.js
chrome-devtools://devtools/devTools.css
```

Comment: Thanks vinilios- nice in browser view- it was a tough call as to who should get the acceptance (if that matters at all). Much appreciated- brings to mind just how time consuming it must have been to implement with unextended JavaScript or without some kind of object production framework. Thanks again.